# partially apply String.prototype... with underscore in javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

With _.partial(f, _, _)(1, 2) I can partially apply and invoke the function f with the two arguments 1 and 2.

Hower this does not seem to work with the Datatype Prototype built-in functions, such as: String.prototype.split.call('a/b/c', '/')

How can I make them work with underscore's partial? This does not work:

_.partial(String.prototype.split.call, _, _)('a/b/c', '/')

Answer (score 1):

String.prototype.split needs 'this' context.

So, below code works.

```
var curried = _.partial(String.prototype.split).bind('a/b/c');
console.log(curried('/'));
```